# Error when adding custom tooltip to plotly graph using ggplotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

This is quite a peculiar problem, so I've included a minimal reproducible example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

example_data <- tibble(
  target = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 6)),
  error = runif(30, -1, 1),
  model = factor(rep(c('Model 1', 'Model 2'), times = 15)),
  type = factor(rep(rep(c('Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3'), each = 2), times = 5))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- example_data %>%
      #mutate(label = paste0(model, ' (', type, ')')) %T>%  # <- doesn't work
      mutate(label = paste0(model, ' (Foo)')) %T>%  # <- does work
      {print(., n = Inf)} %>%  # debugging
      ggplot(aes(x = target, y = error, text = label)) +
        geom_violin(aes(fill = target), show.legend = FALSE) +
        geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
        coord_flip()

    ggplotly(p, tooltip=c('text'))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Essentially, I want to add a custom tooltip to my plotly output in shiny. When I try to do this by combining two columns of my dataset together I get the following error:

```
Warning in max(data$density) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector
```

I'm struggling to decipher how this relates to my code. If on the other hand, I combine one of my columns with a dummy text string (Foo), the tooltips come out fine without an error. You can switch between these two approaches by switching whether line 21/22 are commented.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here but I'm completely stumped as to what is going on. Does anyone have any ideas or might this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out so will share in case anyone comes across this. It turns out that this problem has nothing to do with shiny or plotly, but rather with ggplot.

It appears that setting the `text` aesthetic in the initial mapping has knock-on effects for `geom_violin`. In particular, despite `text` not being a known aesthetic for `geom_violin`, the inclusion of it changes the grouping of the violins. Since the label was unique for each data point, this then left me trying to create a violin plot for each data point by itself - impossible. By setting `group = target` in the `geom_violin` mappings, the problem is fixed.

Hard to tell if this is a bug or a feature so I will strip down the example even further and add it as an issue to the ggplot repo.

Comment: This is not a problem of `geom_violin`. You are passing to `geom_violin` a text variable that is not constant inside a single violin. Try for example using `text = target`, or any other variable which is constant for each violin. `text = label` can be used in `aes` of `geom_jitter`.